# Does any body know how to create binary tree in sql

Tags: php, sql

I am creating MLM website and now I want to build binary tree..
So that user enter their private id and select the sponsor id.

The binary tree should work as follows :

```
1 is root
2 is child of 1
3 is child of 1

Then 4 is child of 2
5 is child of 2

6 is child of 3
7 is child of 3
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maintain `left_child`, `right_child`, and `sponser_id` in each row (record of a member)

```
| ID         |   Name      | left_child  | right_child  | sponser_id |
|:-----------|------------:|:-----------:|:------------:|:----------:|
| 1          |   Root      |     2       |      2       |            |
| 2          |   child-2   |     4       |      5       |     1      |
| 3          |   child-3   |     6       |      7       |     1      |
| 4          |   child-4   |     x       |      y       |     2      |
| 5          |   child-5   |     a       |      b       |     2      |
```

Comment: but after signup.. how can this value autoincrement... left_child or right_child

Comment: this will be blank or 0 if new member is inserted.

Comment: in MLM as you know that a new member only required the sponser id to be register.

Comment: i am proud to be indian... can u tell me the complete process.. that how many columns should be avaible in mysql and with php how can i insert into it...

Comment: new new member contains leg : right or left.. sponsor id , and newuserid

Comment: yes, whenever new member get register ask him to give his sponser id and position (left/right) if position is available insert record of new member with that sponser id(parent_id). now when new member can get register under this new user id.

Comment: if left and right are not blank you can insert the new user in left most or right most of his leg.

Comment: i have created the required columns in my database.. id,name,sponsor_id,right_child,left_child .. now i have my signup form.. but what code now i implement here to insert proper value as desired...

Comment: try now yourself get problem then come back. i will definitly help your.

Comment: sir, i have tried a lot since 3 month.. but i am not understanding this concept... i have created the required table... just i need proper insert code ... I have good knowledge of mysql and php but since now i have not work on binary tree.. so i couldn't understand this concept..

Comment: as i describe the table structure start work on that.

Comment: Sir I have created the table as you said..... but what to do next... I have php signup form.. every time what to insert...

Comment: Sir, I have accomplish the task but just now i want to transform it to php tree view

Comment: @user3133175 Hey can you please share the code you have implemented to spill?